# Idiosyncratic measure on a space of nondecreasing PL paths from the unit interval to itself

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

The image below shows a piecewise linear nondecreasing path from (0,0) to (1,1) produced via a simple random process. First, we pick a point on the diagonal from (0,1) to (1,0) uniformly at random. This produces two rectangles that are shown as darker. We then iteratively pick points uniformly at random on rectangle diagonals and after going down to some depth in a binary tree, we stop and connect the points.

The resulting paths are not exponentially concentrated around the diagonal from (0,0) to (1,1) the way that (e.g.) uniformly random nondecreasing lattice paths would be.

I am wondering if this construction (or a similar one) has been considered in the literature and what if anything is known about it.

[image]